# MVC 6 Authorize only owner or admin

Tags: authorization, asp.net-core-mvc, ownership

I have a user that can have multiple projects. 
I want everybody to see the projects, but only the user that created it, or the admins, should be able to edit it.

I changed the ApplicationUser class that the template provided.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

In the Project class I save the user that created it.

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Then I check in every method if the current user is the owner of the project that he wants to change.

```
    // GET: Projects/Edit/5
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ApplicationUser user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        Project project = _context.Project.Single(m => m.Id == id);
        if (project == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }else if(project.ApplicationUser != user)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(project);
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this ? 
I saw that in MVC 5 you had AuthorizationAttribute, but it's no longer available.

Something like this would be great, but I don't even know where to start:

```
[OwnerAuthorize]
public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
```

EDIT:

I managed to find a way of doing this after reading https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/resourcebased.html

```
public class ProjectAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<OperationAuthorizationRequirement, Project>
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ProjectAuthorizationHandler(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement, Project resource)
    {
        var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(context.User);

        if(userId != null && resource.OwnerId == userId)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And in the controller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var project = await _context.Project.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        if (project == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (!await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, project, Operations.Update))
        {
            return Forbid();
        }

        return View(project);
    }
```

It works, but the only thing that I don't understand is what should I do with the requirement in the HandleRequirementAsync method.

Is this the way to do this in MVC 6 ?